# Working Mark Murphy's Book: Died in Chap 4

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, target

Working the examples in two Android books that were recommended, using win 7, eclipse indigo and the latest Android Tools (updated last night) and : 
Get to the NowRedux example (third example) in Mark Murphy's "Beginning Android 2" (2010) and suddenly I get "Unable to resolve target 'android-6'".

Which leads to two questions:
1) How do I get rid of the apk file, so I can change the target in the properties and build a new one? When I change the target, I get 'invalid apk'.
2) How do I get an 'obsolete' target (6?, Android 2.01, which is what this is) installed, because I can't seem to get his sample to NOT want it? Tried to install it several times, and either run into "can't find the zip file" after it downloads it, or an error about trying to use aapt.exe.

Any help would be appreciated.

As usual, the first effort is not the theory or the language, it's the damned development environment...

Comment: My god man, I thought you died.

Comment: I'm sure you did, but did you try cleaning the project?

Comment: "When I change the target, I get 'invalid apk'" -- where do you "get" 'invalid apk'? "How do I get an 'obsolete' target" -- you don't want it. I have no idea where `android-6` came from on your copy. The [current copy of that project in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Layouts/NowRedux) is set for `android-4`. Since the ZIP archive wasn't set up with Eclipse projects, you would have defined the build target manually. BTW, the GitHub repo has Eclipse project files for this project for use with File|Import.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Got the newest .zip down, but I'm having a bit of fun trying to get the path for the various directories correct. Tried the File|Import, ended up with "'/NowRedux/res' does not exist", but that's probably due to the same set-up or import issue that leads to the main.xml thinking it's at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\commonsguy-cw-android-v3.7-6-gbcf7878\commonsguy-cw-android-bcf7878\Layouts\NowRedux\res\layout\main.xml". I'll get it figured out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Android 2.0.1 (android-6) was an minor release and it is deprecated since Android 2.1 (android-7) is out. Use "android-7" target instead of "android-6" and all will be ok.